# Collecting data using socket()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My final aim is to collect the data from my ESP32 WROOM (a node mcu) and then save all the incoming data into the csv file on my pc. For that I am using the socket function, but when I run the code and try to print the incoming values to see whether or not I am getting any output I am not seeing anything.

I am able to send data using ESP32 WROOM since, I have checked it on the SerialWiFiterminal app on phone and all the data that I am transmitting is being received as it is. But when I try to receive the data using socket() on my PC it's showing as "Client not connected to server".

Can someone help me in understanding what the issue here is since, I am using socket() for the first time and didn't really find anything online regarding this.

The following is the python code:

```
import socket

port = 80
format = 'utf-8'
server = "192.168.19.2"
addr = (server,port)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connect = client.connect(addr)

if client== True:
    print("Client connected to server")
else:
    print("Client not connected to server")

print(client.recv(1048).decode(format))
```

Here is my ESP 32 WROOM code for reference:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>


int value = 3;
//int value = 3;
const char *ssid = "LANZ"; //ESP Access Point
const char *password = "123456789"; //ESP Password

WiFiClient client;
IPAddress ip (192, 168, 19, 2);
IPAddress netmask  (255, 255, 255, 0);
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000); //Wait to run ESP properly

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, ip, netmask);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  Serial.println("Wifi Details:");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(password);
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Error! Please make sure to connect to LANZ");
    Serial.println("Please manually add LANZ to your phone");
    Serial.println();
    //delay(2000);
    client = server.available();
    return;
  }
  if(client.connected()){
    if(Serial.available()){
      value = Serial.read();
      client.write(value);
      }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens on the PC side? "Unable to do so" doesn't help...

Comment: it just shows a blank screen. The code runs but no output is shown or the text message that the socket code is connected to my esp or not.

Comment: You're only listening to the first 1048 bytes but your driver looks to be writing bytes in a loop. Also, `format` in python is a reserved word and `decode()` defaults to utf-8.

Comment: @digitalnomd I am getting 4 bytes data every 2 seconds. The ESP32 WROOM is connected to an FPGA which does some calculations and every 2 seconds i get 4 bytes of data. When viewed in the SerialWiFiTerminal app on mobile I am getting those 4 bytes of data every 2 seconds without any issues


We have also tried the code by just writing  `print(client.recv(1048).decode())` but the results were the same

Comment: `print(client.recv(1048).decode(format))` will receive a _single_ buffer of max size 1048. It sounds like there are packets of size 4 bytes sent every 2 seconds which means that you're receiving separate messages. to see the same in your script you'll need to include a `while` loop.

Comment: @digitalnomd I was running the code once again and now instead of not showing any output it displays the message not connected to the server. I have updated the question and attached the snippet